# i have a table and i wish the resultant table as i shown in my description

Tags: sql-server, vba

i have a table like this

```
create table TA1
(
col1 int,col2 int,pk1 int,uom1 varchar(20),pck2 int,uom2 varchar(20)
)  

insert into ta1 values(15,18,6,'a',1,'b')
insert into ta1 values(17,12,61,'c',1,'d')
```

i have created another table like this `

```
create table ta2(col int,pck int,uom varchar(20))
```

i need to get the resultant output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *Unpivot* the data. Use `CROSS APPLY` operator to do this

```
Insert into ta2(col, pck, uom)
SELECT col, 
       pck, 
       uom 
FROM   ta1 
       CROSS apply (VALUES (col1, pk1, uom1), 
                           (col2, pck2, uom2)) 
      cs (col, pck, uom)
```

Or you can use `UNION ALL` to get the result in desired format

```
select  col1 as col, pk1 as pck, uom1 as uom from ta1
union all
select col2, pck2, uom2 from ta1
```

Comment: @Naveen - I am a database guy dont know about VB

Comment: the table2 will be empty initially, so i need to insert these values into that table

Comment: @Naveen - check now